# convert json string to object and back $.post work $.ajax not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I just now understanding that array in js not able to contain key to value so I was looking option to pass array from js to php and back. when I serch information about that I found the json option.
but I see that js not support completely unless you add plugin in my case json2.js .
I have two diffrent code which  `$.post` work well and  `$.ajax` not work.
I will be glad if you tell me why `$.ajax` not working you have full code which you can test.
 the json2.js is from [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).thx
`$.ajax` code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: "phpfile.php",
            data: "{ data : dataString }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
               alert('sucsses');
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
        if(obj.somebool === true)
          $("#result").html(obj.hello + ' ' + obj.array[1] + obj.worked + ". Message from PHP: "+obj.php_message);
            },
            error: alert ('there was problem with ajax');
        });
```

*
    `$.post` code:

```
    $.post('phpfile.php', {data: dataString}, function(res){
      alert('sucsses');
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
        if(obj.somebool === true)
          $("#result").html(obj.hello + ' ' + obj.array[1] + obj.worked + ". Message from PHP: "+obj.php_message);
      });
```

html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Json Test</title>
<SCRIPT src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></SCRIPT> 
<SCRIPT src="json2.js"></SCRIPT> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = new Object();
  data.hello = "Hello";
  data.world = 'World';
  data.worked = " it worked ";
  data.somebool = true;
  data.array = new Array("he\"ll\"o", '"World"');
  alert (data.hello);
  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
  alert(dataString);
  $.post('phpfile.php', {data: dataString}, function(res){
  alert('sucsses');
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
    if(obj.somebool === true)
      $("#result").html(obj.hello + ' ' + obj.array[1] + obj.worked + ". Message from PHP: "+obj.php_message);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$res = json_decode($_REQUEST['data'], true);
$res["php_message"] = "I am PHP";
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

Comment: The json2 library is not needed if you have jQuery - as you show there is `jQuery.parseJSON`.

Comment: In which browser did you test this code? Because JSON global object is not available in some browsers.That is why you need json2.js.

Answer (score 2):

In your `$.ajax()` request you've set `dataType: 'json'`, which means that the response will already be a JSON object rather than a string representing one. Therefore, calling `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);` in your callback function won't actually do anything helpful for you. Just work with `res` directly.

The equivalent `$.post()` function call would pass the optional `dataType` argument to the function, like so:

```
$.post('phpfile.php', {data: dataString}, function(res){
    alert('sucsses');
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
    if(obj.somebool === true)
        $("#result").html(obj.hello + ' ' + obj.array[1] + obj.worked + ". Message from PHP: "+obj.php_message);
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that you're sending:

```
data: "{ data : dataString }",
```

This is just a string but not valid JSON. The `dataString` part are just some string characters which don't refer to anything. You probably mean:

```
data: { data : dataString },
```

This is a real object which does refer to `dataString`, and the object is converted to JSON.